# How to add and remove relationship through queries in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`User` and `Bid` are two ActiveRecord models. I want to add add and remove relationship through queries.

I tried

```
User.find(1).bids.find(1).destroy
```

but this deletes the record. Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Which record are you trying to delete, the `Bid` or the `User`? Also, do you want to delete the association (i.e. decouple the records) or delete the record itself?

Answer (score 0):

Depends a bit on how you've set up your associations in the model.

This would delete the first bid for user with id 1.

```
User.find(1).bids.first.destroy
```

This would create a new bid for user with id 1.

```
User.find(1).bids.create(name: "name")
```

**Update:**

A user has 0:N bids. This is setup so that when you destroy a relationship between bid and user it deletes the bid.  If you want to keep the bid (kind of odd I think?) you need a m:n association.  Try a [has_many, :through](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) if you want this.

For your current setup 0:N, each bid you want to destroy you can do by getting the User then finding the specific bid(s) you want to destroy. To find the bids you need the bid ID.  `User.find(1).bids.find(1).destroy` is looking for User with id = 1 and their bid with id = 1. If this does not exist it will not delete it. By using `bids.first` (as above) it will find User with id = 1 then get that users first bid.

If you want to delete multiple bids for a user, but not the user, you can use `destroy_all`.

This will get all bids with id of 1 or 2 for User with id=1 and destroy them.

```
User.find(1).bids.where(id: [1,2]).destroy_all
```

If you don't know the ids you could use `all.limit(2)` which will destroy the first 2 bids for the user (2 can be any number of bids). `all` returns an ActiveRecord::AssociationRelation.

```
User.find(1).bids.all.limit(2).destroy_all
```

Comment: User has relationship with Bid one-to-many.If User have relationship with 10 bids and i want to remove relationship with any 3 bids please suggest me query in that case.

Comment: This is not a good approach by the try to **create object** first and then make te relationships among two tables.
Instead of this because in this case may be u miss some input for columns

Comment: @AqibHameed You can use validations in your model set mandatory fields in your DB to ensure necessary fields are filled out.

Answer (score 0):

If you add this options your model

```
has_many :bids, dependent: :destroy
```

you can do this:

```
User.find(1).destroy  # this will destroy all bids you have in this association
```

or you can use this:

```
User.find(1).bids.destroy_all
```